# Quisiera saber como almacenar todos los datos obtenidos en un excel o en alguna base de datos

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
for i in range(0, D.shape[0]):
                        for j in range(i + 1, D.shape[1]):
                                # verifica si la distancia entre dos
                                # pares de centroides es menor que el número configurado
                                # de píxeles
                                p1.append(i)
                                p2.append(j)
                                d.append(D[i, j])
                                d1.append(D[i, j]*(2/50)) 
                                
                                if ((i!=j)&(D[i, j] < config.MIN_DISTANCE)):
                                        # actualizar nuestra violación establecida con los índices de
                                        # los pares de centroides
                                        violate.add(i)
                                        violate.add(j)
                                        p11.append(i)
                                        p12.append(j)
                                        d12.append(D[i, j])
                                        d13.append(D[i, j]*(2/50))                                               
                                                                
                                        df1=pd.DataFrame({"p1":p11,"p2":p12,"Dis en pixeles":d12,"dist en metros":d13})#Si no quieres las distancias de las violaciones ponle en comentario
                                        print(df1)#al igual que el anterior ponle en comentario
                                #df1.to_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name='example') si necesitas un excel con valores
                                #df=pd.DataFrame({"p1":p1,"p2":p2,"Dis en pixeles":d,"dist en metros":d1})  Si necesitas todos lo valores detectados quita el numeral
                                #print(df)
                                #df.to_excel('example1.xlsx', sheet_name='example') #Todos estos comentarios
```

Estos es la parte del código, osea quisiera que me imprimiera bajo de lo que una vez se imprimió, pero no estoy seguro como realizarlo, no he trabajado mucho con pandas

Comment: Por favor, revisa tu código (?).

Comment: El codígo es mucho mas largo, solo que puse la parte del problema, quisiera saber como seguir enviando datos, y que se impriman hacia abajo